# How to merge two lists in to one flatten is not working

Tags: groovy

I have two lists and i would like to merge into one list.

```
def values = [[name:"A",prof:"B"],[exp:["C","E"]]]

def list3=values.flatten();  //flatten is not working
println ("list 2 is"+list3);
```

Result is same

```
[[name:A, prof:B], [exp:[C, E]]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[name:A, prof:B, exp:[C, E]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten will reduce nesting in lists

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].flatten() == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What you have is a non-nested list of maps

Flatten will have no effect

To get the result you're expecting, you want to add all the maps together

You can do this with `values.sum()`